# Can't receive UDP data unless Wireshark is running

Tags: networking, wireshark, windows-firewall, udp

We have a computer system (Win10) that receives a variety of UDP data from a remote host at various rates (2-50Hz). The remote system is provided by our customer. While we're waiting for the customer to deliver this system, they have provided a Wireshark capture of their UDP data stream. We are replaying that pcap data from a temporary system (192.168.6.1) over the network to our system (192.168.6.2 port 8001). The IP addresses in the pcap file match the addresses used by our computers in our lab.

The problem is that when we replay the pcap recording (running [ColaSoft Packet Player](https://www.colasoft.com/packet_player/)) to re-roadcast the UDP data, our system ONLY can receive the UDP data if we are running Wireshark on the same computer.

Some things I've looked at:

- Running `netstat -a -b -o -p UDP` on our system shows that our software is registered as listening for UDP traffic on port 8001
- The Windows 10 firewall has all ports completely open at this time
- UDP data is not received at all until I start Wireshark on the same computer
- Re-running `netstat -a -b -o -p UDP` after Wireshark has started strangely does not show that WS is also listening on UDP port 8001
- CPU utilization is very low, less than 10% of the CPU is being used (this is a dual-socket Intel Xeon)
- As soon as Wireshark is started, our software begins to receive the UDP data (though strangely we are dropping a few packets as well)

This certainly sounds like some sort of configuration issue, and I would have guessed firewall but it is completely open. I certainly am interested in hearing what I've missed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wireshark puts the network interface in "promiscuous" mode, as do most other packet capture tools.

Primarily, this causes the hardware to accept frames sent to the "wrong" destination MAC address. This used to be more relevant with historical "bus" networks, where all NICs saw all packets. On a modern switched Ethernet, the switch normally wouldn't deliver misaddressed frames to your Ethernet port in the first place.

But if you're replaying the same pcap on a different network, where the original destination MAC doesn't exist at all, then the switches will still blast these frames through all ports – only to be ignored by all devices due to MAC mismatch (but not without contributing to the network load across the entire subnet). In this situation, only devices running in promisc mode will accept those frames.

So my guess is that you've tried to configure the same IP address on a different host to receive the replayed packets, but it nevertheless has a different MAC address and ignores the frames because of that...

I would expect your packet player to have a function to replace MAC addresses. The Linux *tcpreplay* toolkit comes with [tcprewrite](https://tcpreplay.appneta.com/wiki/tcprewrite-man.html) for this purpose.

Comment: Very interesting. You are correct that we're replaying the pcap on a different network with different computers. Is there a way to edit the expected MAC address (source or destination) in the pcap file to match the MAC on the current network?

Comment: Your packet replayer, or alternatively the _tcpreplay_ toolkit on Linux, should have that function somewhere.